# Proper permissions for ETL user

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm working on changing the permissions on our ETL to incorporate best practices.

This is our ETL in a nutshell:

1. Load 100+ tables from 5 different SQL Servers into stage in DW
2. Call procedures on stage and ODS databases to transform the data
3. Log the executions to a logging database

This is scheduled via a job.

What would be the appropriate permissions for this ETLUser account? Here are my thoughts:

- Change to non-admin domain account
- assign db_datareader on source databases
- db_datareader, db_datawriter on Stage, ODS and Logging databases.
- db_executor role (custom) on Stage, ODS and Logging
- db_ddladmin on Stage (for truncating)
- Is a proxy account on the job required?

SQL Server 2012

Comment: The biggest security concern (but I know why you're doing it) is the `db_ddladmin` role membership.  We've sometimes used a stored proc to get around that limitation by allowing the stored proc to `EXECUTE AS` a trusted user, and having it do the truncate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thoughts are to the point.

The only thing I want to suggest is not to use the db_ddladmin account if you only want to truncate tables. 
The minimum permission for truncating a table is ALTER, see [Truncate Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570(v=sql.110).aspx). So you could make a custom database role with ALTER permissions on all tables you need to truncate. Assign that role to the ETLUser account.

A proxy account is in my opinion indeed the best way to run the package under the ETLUser account in an SQL Server agent job.